# What is the purpose of tf.compat?

Tags: tensorflow

What's the purpose of tf.compat module? It looks like just the entire Tensorflow API is replicated inside this module.
The documentation states

> Functions for Python 2 vs. 3 compatibility.

So why there is a "v1" and a "v2" submodule? What are the compatibility problems address by tf.compat specifically?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`tf.compat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat) allows you to write code that works both in TensorFlow 1.x and 2.x. For example, the following piece of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [2])
    x2 = tf.square(x)
    print(sess.run(x2, feed_dict={x: [2, 3]}))
    # [4. 9.]
```

Runs the same on TensorFlow 1.15.0 and 2.0.0, even though session and placeholders were deprecated in 2.x. Likewise, [`tf.compat.v2`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v2) allows you to use things introduced in 2.x from 1.x. Also, these APIs provide also backwards compatibility for the future too, so if at some point a 3.x version is released, the mechanism to write version-independent code will already be there since the first version of 2.x.

EDIT: The documentation for the module about Python should actually be changed. Originally, `tf.compat` only held functions for that purpose (and it was like that until 1.13, [see all module documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.13/api_docs/python/tf/compat)). However, it was later repurposed for TensorFlow version compatibility.

Comment: According to tensorflow website tensorflow_gpu-1.15.0 is compatible with CUDA 10.0