# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'AdagradOptimizer'

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, video, recommendation-engine

When I call the following model using TensorFlow, I face the above error.
How can I fix it?

```
model = SkipGramModel(vocab_size, val_set, 
embedding_dims=256,batch_size=batch_size, sample_factor=1., lr=lr)###, 
optimizer= tf.train.AdagradOptimizer)
```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adagrad)? You can also consider the compatability options, namely [`tf.compat.v1.train.AdagradOptimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/AdagradOptimizer). The problem likely occurs because you're using TensorFlow 2.X, while `tf.train.AdagradOptimizer` is only for TF 1.X.

Comment: should I downgrade Tensorflow to TF1.X ??

Comment: You could do that, or you could just use the `tf.compat.v1.train.AdagradOptimizer`. Basically `tf.compat.v1` allows you to use TF 1.X's depurated functions in TF 2.X. For more information, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631390/what-is-the-purpose-of-tf-compat).

Comment: Yes, I did the same and it works.:).   But I faced this error: "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'optimizer'" in the following code:                            model = SkipGramModel(vocab_size, val_set, embedding_dims=256, 
                      batch_size=batch_size, sample_factor=1., lr=lr, optimizer= tf.compat.v1.train.AdagradOptimizer)
"""training"""