# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat' running in Pycharm

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I run in Pycharm:
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.**version**)

I got error:
"C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\python.exe" "C:/Users/Hoi Yee/PycharmProjects/untitled1/ss.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Hoi Yee/PycharmProjects/untitled1/ss.py", line 1, in 
import tensorflow as tf
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py", line 101, in 
from tensorflow_core import *
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core_*init*_.py", line 46, in 
from . *api.v2 import compat
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core_api\v2\compat_*init**.py", line 39, in 
from . import v1
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core_api\v2\compat\v1_*init*_.py", line 32, in 
from . import compat
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core_api\v2\compat\v1\compat_*init*_.py", line 39, in 
from . import v1
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\v1_*init*_.py", line 29, in 
from tensorflow.*api.v2.compat.v1 import app
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core_api\v2\compat_*init**.py", line 39, in 
from . import v1
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core_api\v2\compat\v1_*init*_.py", line 32, in 
from . import compat
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core_api\v2\compat\v1\compat_*init*_.py", line 39, in 
from . import v1
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\v1_*init*_.py", line 667, in 
from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api.*v1 import estimator
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator_*init**.py", line 10, in 
from tensorflow_estimator.*api.v1 import estimator
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator_api\v1\estimator_*init**.py", line 10, in 
from tensorflow_estimator.*api.v1.estimator import experimental
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator_api\v1\estimator\experimental_*init**.py", line 10, in 
from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py", line 33, in 
from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 53, in 
from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import util as estimator_util
File "C:\Users\Hoi Yee\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\util.py", line 75, in 
class _DatasetInitializerHook(tf.compat.v1.train.SessionRunHook):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat'

Process finished with exit code 1

how to solve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat' when loading tf.compat.v1.train.SessionRunHook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622704/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-compat-when-loading-tf-co)

Answer (score 0):

how did you import it?

perhaps, this one might help you:

```
import tensorflow._api.v2.feature_column as fc
```

... since "**import tensorflow.compat.v2.feature_column as fc**" *is not working (yet in pycharm, in feb 2021 ..)*

about:

> "tf.compat allows you to write code that works both in TensorFlow 1.x
> and 2.x. For example, the following piece of code:"
> source: [What is the purpose of tf.compat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631390/what-is-the-purpose-of-tf-compat)