# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat' on TFOD Course

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, pip

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\Obejct Detection\TFODCourse\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'
```

Hello, Currently i'm following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqkISICHH-U&t=18919s Tutorial, but at time 1.50.30 when it comes to installing tensorflow, i always get this error code, and i can't solve it however i install tensorflof, i'm using python 3.10 and tensorflow 2.12.0. and i'm running jupyter via anaconda

I already following the tutorial step by step, but still can't solve the error, and i also watching previous question about this, but still can't find the resolvement

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631390/what-is-the-purpose-of-tf-compat

Comment: How did you install these Python packages? Are you using `conda` to install the packages? https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/#How-to-use-Conda-from-the-Jupyter-Notebook

Answer (score 1):

it can be due to the version of tensorflow you are using either you simply use tensorflow or you install version 1.15 with 'pip install tensorflow==1:15' wich is compatible with 'tensorflow.compat.v1'